# ASP.MVC 3 AJAX JSON won't serialize to Rectangle or Custom Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm using the jquery plugin Jcrop for custom image resizing and am having an issue passing the data to MVC in a way that it will interpreter it correctly when passing the arguments to the method call.

Here is what my Ajax call looks like

```
var cropArea = { X: 50, Y: 50, Width: 200, Height: 200 };
var destSize = { Width: 200, Height: 200 };
$.ajax ({
    url: "image/CropImage",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: image.id, cropArea: cropArea, size: destSize }),
    dataType: "json"
});
```

and the C# code looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResizeImage(int id, Rectangle cropArea, Size size)
{
    // Crop Code here
}
```

The Id comes in just fine but the Rectangle and Size object will not, I just get a null exception error for cropArea and size. I can pass the rectangle and size params in as arrays but I'd rather have the Rectangle and Size objects passed in

Comment: use this article. http://erraticdev.blogspot.in/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery ajax code is missing the `contentType` parameter:

```
var cropArea = { X: 50, Y: 50, Width: 200, Height: 200 };
var cropArea = { X: 50, Y: 50, Width: 200, Height: 200 };
var destSize = { Width: 200, Height: 200 };
$.ajax({
    url: "image/CropImage",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: image.id, cropArea: cropArea, size: destSize }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

I have quickly tested that using a dummy method in my home controller and some dummy classes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResizeImage(int id, Rectangle cropArea, Size size)
{
    // Crop Code here
    return Json(true);
}

public class Rectangle
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class Size
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Posting with this code when I click on a button:

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    var cropArea = { X: 50, Y: 50, Width: 200, Height: 200 };
    var destSize = { Width: 200, Height: 200 };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/ResizeImage",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: 210, cropArea: cropArea, size: destSize }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!